# Using printf to printf to print a part of string

Tags: c, string, io, printf

For example, I have a string and I want to write a function that will printf a part of it to the screen with the length printed is not initialized but defined latter wether by function or input data

normally

```
char str[70]="my name is Jack";
printf("%.4s", str[11])
```

the result will be "Jack"

However now the length to be written to stdout now is now specified

```
char str[70]="my name is Jack";
int x;
scanf("%d",&x);
```

now I the length will be define later so How to use it with printf
I now just using this method

```
char str[70]="my name is Jack";
int x, i;
scanf("%d",&x);
for(i=0, i<x, i++){
    printf("%c", str[11+i]);
```

this will work but I want to know is there any way to printf without using loop. I tried

```
printf("%.xc", str[11+i]);
```

but the result is incorrect, so this is not the way.

Comment: `scanf("%d",x);` should be `scanf("%d",&x);`.

Comment: `printf("%.4s", str[11])` should be `printf("%.4s", str + 11)`

Answer (score 3):

Use `*` in the printf conversion specifier

```
char data[] = "The name is Jack Monroe";
int length = 4;
int start = 12;
printf("%.*s", length, data + start); // Jack
```

Comment: Hi, can you give me some reference of * conversion specifer, I use google but the result doesn't satisfy me

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html "An optional precision that gives ... the maximum number of bytes to be printed from a string in the s conversion specifier."

Comment: Also http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1 for the same text